# rails cancan gem,, can method in ability.rb how to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

i'm using cancan gem but i'm a bit confused.
what is the difference:

```
  can :read, Post
  can :read, :post
  can :read, @post
```

What is the better(secure) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
can :read Post
```

indicates that a user can read any post, as it references the model in general

```
can :read @post
can :read :post
```

indicates that a user can read that specific post (usually because the post has a belongs_to association with the user or something like that)

an example of how to set up your abilities page:

```
if user.admin?
  can :read Post #admin can read any post
else
  can :read Post, :user_id => user.id #non-admins can read only posts that belong to them.
end
```

Comment: I've never seen @post or :post being used to define abilities. Usually you use those in the controller or view when checking if a user can perform an action on a specific instance of a model.  ie. if (can? :read @post) ... do some stuff

Comment: i have seen this usage in the official doc and in https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb